# Error while uploading file with metadata to API using HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, httpwebrequest

I'm consuming an API to upload file with metadata using HttpWebRequest class in C#, but while I am debugging the code it returned is 400 ERROR.

Please help me to figure out the problem. I've attached the image of API reference below.

[image]
Below, I attached metadata which has to be passed

```
{
"summary":"test",
"owners":[
"TEST_user"
],
"managers":[
"TESTECM.TESTECM"
],
"receivedDate":"2016-07-25T16:54:34+1000",
"status":"20",
"folders":[
"b26e2b79-1693-4138-b42e-ac49b46104eb"
],
"docType":"INT",
"contentType":"1",
"extRefNo":"123456",
"htmlContent":"Sample Content"
}
```

**bellow i attached C# code which i have tried**

```
public class FileUploadMetaDatas
{
    public string summary = "test";
    // public string owners = "TESTECM";
    public string[] owners = new string[] { "TESTECM_user" };
    //public string managers = "TESTECM.TESTECM";
    public string[] managers = new string[] { "TESTECM.TESTECM" };
    public string receivedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    public string status = "20";
    //public string folders = "b26e2b79-1693-4138-b42e-ac49b46104eb";
    public string[] folders = new string[] { "b26e2b79-1693-4138-b42e-ac49b46104eb" };
    public string docType = "INT";
    public string contentType = "1";
    public string extRefNo = "123456";
    public string htmlContent = "Sample Content";
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var AccessTokenValue = "1ybht6c-a0ef-47e6-9d57-0655tygy73952";
            FileUploadMetaDatas FUMD = new FileUploadMetaDatas();
            var Imagefile = "https://www.logaster.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/jpg.png";

            string jsonMetaModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FUMD);
            string postFileData = "meta=" + jsonMetaModel + "&file=" + Imagefile;
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] filebytess = encoding.GetBytes(postFileData);
            string Uploaduri = "https://testwebserverdev.test.com:8493/testecm/rest/docs";

            HttpWebRequest requestUpload = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uploaduri);
            requestUpload.Method = "POST";
            requestUpload.PreAuthenticate = true;
            requestUpload.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessTokenValue);
            requestUpload.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            requestUpload.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            //requestUpload.Accept = "application/json";
            requestUpload.ContentLength = filebytess.Length;

            Stream newStream = requestUpload.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(filebytess, 0, filebytess.Length);

            HttpWebResponse respofnse = (HttpWebResponse)requestUpload.GetResponse();

            // get the response content
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respofnse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            var respofnskuie = reader.ReadToEnd();
            //Console.WriteLine(respofnskuie);
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(respofnskuie);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.access_token);
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex+"NOT WORKING");
        }                    
    }                                                 
}
```

Comment: Is it your own API? Can you debug the API code?

Comment: No, its 3rd party api..

Comment: 400 error indicates that there is some problem with the request or the data sent in the request. You need to read the documentation of the APIs and understand how exactly you need to make a request to the API. Along with the 400 error the API also might be returning some response content with proper error code and the description of the error. That will might give you idea about why it is failing.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Its returned only previous error line only "{"The remote server returned an error: (400)  ."}" ,In API reference they told us to pass  Authorization [Bearer <access token>],Content-Type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] to HEADER and meta,file in BODY (multipart/form-data) section..

Comment: You may have more than one problem but you are [overwriting the content type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) to `multipart/form-data`. Your post data might also require form url encoding.